# How can i close popup box when selecting image from folder with imacros

Tags: imacros

I need tot take picture from folder and upload to website, but how do i close popup box after upload image. Here is my code

```
URL GOTO=https://www.kijiji.ca/p-post-ad.html?categoryId=168
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ACTION:/p-submit-ad.html ATTR=TXT:Select<SP>Images
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:FILE FORM=ACTION:/p-submit-ad.html ATTR=* CONTENT=D:\images\download.jpg
WAIT SECONDS=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this....

```
URL GOTO=https://www.kijiji.ca/p-post-ad.html?categoryId=168
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:FILE FORM=ACTION:/p-submit-ad.html ATTR=* CONTENT=D:\images\download.jpg
wait seconds=5
```